# Can I replace HTML text in an element by using vanilla JS as so? e.target.innerHTML.replace('old text', 'new text');

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

```
const tour = document.querySelector('.tour__heading');
const addSection = e => {
        e.target.innerHTML.replace('SHOW','red');
};
tour.addEventListener('click', addSection);
```

Can I use e.target to change HTML text as above?

Comment: `replace` doesn't change the string in-place (strings are immutable in JS). You would need to set the `innerHTML` equal to the return value of `.replace()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `String.prototype.replace` function will replace the content of a string but not modify the original.

You can either do:

```js
e.target.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML.replace('SHOW','red')
```

Or you can create a polyfill for a custom function on the `HTMLElement` object.

```js
/* A polyfill for a custom HTML text replacer function */
if (HTMLElement.prototype.replaceHTML === undefined) {
  HTMLElement.prototype.replaceHTML = function(regexpOrSubstr, newSubstrOrFunc) {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace.apply(this.innerHTML, arguments)
  }
}

const tour = document.querySelector('.tour__heading')
const addSection = e => {
  //e.target.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML.replace('SHOW','red')
  e.target.replaceHTML('SHOW','red')
}
tour.addEventListener('click', addSection)
```

```css
.tour__heading:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="tour__heading">SHOW</div>
```

---

### Update

A preferable approach is to avoid polluting the `prototype`. The optimal method for achieving this involves leveraging functional programming principles. Rather than adding a method to each DOM `Element` individually, a more effective strategy is to pass the `Element` as an argument to a function.

Here is a modern function (JSDoc included) that replaces the inner HTML of an element and returns the modified object:

```js
/**
 * Replaces the innerHTML of a given DOM element based on a specified pattern
 * and replacement.
 *
 * @param {Element} element - The target DOM element to modify.
 * @param {String|RegExp} pattern - The search pattern to match within the
       innerHTML.
 * @param {String|Function} replacement - The string or function used for
       replacement.
 *     If a function, it receives the matched substring and should return the
 *     replacement string.
 * @return {Element} The original modified element with updated innerHTML.
 */
const replaceHTML = (element, pattern, replacement) => {
  const { innerHTML } = element;
  return Object.assign(element, {
    innerHTML: innerHTML.replace(pattern, replacement)
  });
};

document.querySelector('.click-me')
  .addEventListener('click', e => {
    replaceHTML(e.target, /\b(?:really)\b/g, 'very')
  })
```

```css
.click-me:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="click-me">A really really really long title</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Nick Parson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons) mentioned, `String.replace()` is a pure function. It returns a new value but doesn't mutate the existing one.

```js
const initialText = 'initial';
const changedText = initialText.replace('initial', 'changed');

console.log(changedText);
console.log(initialText);
```

---

I would recommend using `textContent` instead. Since you only want to work with text inside of an element. It's safer.

---

```js
const tour = document.querySelector('.tour__heading');
const addSection = e => {
        const text = e.target.textContent;
        const updatedText = text.replace('SHOW','red');
        e.target.textContent = updatedText;
};
tour.addEventListener('click', addSection);
```

```html
<h1 class="tour__heading">
  SHOW
</h1>
```